# What is this connector called? TDS Meter connector

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design

I am trying to extend my sensor's cable as it is only 50cm.
I do not want to cut the cable in case I want to revert back. The sensor has a male 2 pin connector on the end and the board has the female connector

I just want to know what the connector is called please.

P.S should I expect any issues with extending an analog cable by 50cm to 100cm ?

[image: picture of board with the 2 pin connector]

Comment: It looks like a cartoon connector.

Comment: Google JST or molex connectors. Like "jst 2mm connector" or so in pictures. They have different sizes and pitches (distance between pins, some have 1mm, some 1.27, some 2mm, 2.54). Measure yours (distance between pins most important, outer look is obvious), and find the one that has the same shape and pitch. It should do the trick

Comment: similar question was asked in the last two days ... it is a JST XH connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part number is listed in your TDS meters documentation:

https://wiki.keyestudio.com/KS0429_keyestudio_TDS_Meter_V1.0

> Electrode Interface: XH2.54-2P